# How to convert a numeric vector into dates?

Tags: r, date

I need to convert the following vector called DATE into dates using "date":

```
DATE <- c(2015-03-20, 2015-03-23, 2015-03-24, 2015-03-25, 2015-03-26, 2015-03-27, 2015-03-30, 2015-03-31)
```

I can't figure out how to convert the vector into date without adding quotes "" to each value the vector hold:

```
DATE <- as.Date(c("2015-03-20", "2015-03-23", "2015-03-24", "2015-03-25", "2015-03-26", "2015-03-27", "2015-03-30", "2015-03-31"))
```

Is there a class called "date" (without capital D) that can automatically convert the vector into date?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm curious how you got the input in that format

Comment: Look at the result of your first vector. What it is asking R to do is subtract 3 and 20 from 2015 and so on.

Comment: The `Hmisc`package has a nice function `Cs()` which creates a vector of of character strings from unquoted names. So, you can try `lubridate::ymd(Hmisc::Cs(2015-03-20, 2015-03-23, 2015-03-24, 2015-03-25, 2015-03-26, 2015-03-27, 2015-03-30, 2015-03-31))`.

Answer (score 3):

I not sure how one would end up with that kind of input. As it is, the input is being subtracted as numbers (`2015 - 03 - 20 = 1992`) before being stored in the variable.

You'd need to provide a string input. However, there is no need to add `"` to each individual values. You can read the whole thing as one string (add `"` only at the beginning and at the end) and then process it using R. Specifically, use `strsplit` the split the string at `,` and then convert the values to date using `as.Date`. Read `?strptime` to learn more about `format`.

```
DATE <- c("2015-03-20, 2015-03-23, 2015-03-24, 2015-03-25, 2015-03-26, 2015-03-27, 2015-03-30, 2015-03-31")
DATE = unlist(strsplit(DATE,", ")) #Split into individual values and convert to array
as.Date(as.character(DATE), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2015-03-20" "2015-03-23" "2015-03-24" "2015-03-25" "2015-03-26" "2015-03-27" "2015-03-30" "2015-03-31"
```

Comment: `lubridate::ymd(Hmisc::Cs(2015-03-20, 2015-03-23, 2015-03-24, 2015-03-25, 2015-03-26, 2015-03-27, 2015-03-30, 2015-03-31))` works as well.